# (PHP,xampp) syntax error in every code I test

Tags: php, xampp, syntax-error

I get a " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected" error for whatever I print.

The error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"test"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\firstfile\test.php on line 3"

The code I tested

```
<?php

 echo 'test';

  
 ?>
```

A basic code, but the error persist.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that what you posted is not the actual file that is executed? Certainly that file is fine syntactically, so there must be some stupid mistake somewhere. I see that the faulty file is inside a folder firstfile. You are really sure this posted file is that file inside the folder?

What is especially outstanding here are the double quote chars in the error message which simply are not present in the file you posted.

When an error like this remains unchanged whatever you do, then typically you edit the wrong file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to make many files an folders, but no use. I will try to reinstall "xampp".  It was the last resort.Thanks.

Comment: Ok, but the idea is not to make many attempts in the hope that something works, but to narrow the issue down. I suggest you remove _all_ files from the htdocs folder, really wipe it, not just a bit. Then make a test request which should give an error "not found". Then create a single _new_ file and request that.

Comment: I tried that, but the same error occurs.  I tried to change the encoding to "UCS-2" and then return it to ANSI again, and the file worked like a magic!. I really have no idea what the cause of the problem. But thanks your comment gave me a hint to try that.

Comment: Which encoding did you change?

Comment: The test.php file  from ANSI to "UCS-2 and then returned it back.

Comment: Ok, in that case I suggest you compare that twice-converted file with one you create as before (use a hexeditor for that) and find out the difference. Because aparently something is _really_ borked on your system. You should solve that, otherwise you will run into problems again and again.

Comment: I'll try to figure out the problem by comparing the two files. Thank you

Comment: Remember: use a hexeditor. There is no other way to really check encoding of files. Every other means disguises the real content by trying to guess and interpret which clearly is what you do _not_ want here. You need a raw, unfiltered view on the content. Hexeditor.

Comment: I will keep that in my mind, Thank you very much  arkascha . Best Wishes.